# Does this graph algorithm have a name?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $\Gamma=(V,E)$ be a graph with vertices $V$ and edges $E$.
Let $f_0: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be a function that assigns a non-negative number to each vertex.
Assume that $f_0$ is not identically zero.
Execute the following algorithm:

1. Given $f_i$, define $\overline{f_i}$ as $\overline{f_i}(v):=\frac{f_i(v)}{\sum_{w \in V} f_i(w)}$, i.e. make $\overline{f_i}$ sum up to $1$.
2. Given $\overline{f_i}$, define $f_{i+1}$ via $f_{i+1}(v):=\overline{f}_i(v)+\sum_{(v,w) \in E} \overline{f}_i(w)$, i.e. $f_{i+1}$ is given up by summing up the values of $\overline{f_i}$ in a $1$-neighbourhood.

I think this converges in the sense that $\overline{f_i}(v) \rightarrow \frac{deg(v)+1}{deg(\Gamma)+|V|}$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$ for all $v \in V$, where $deg(\Gamma)$ denotes the total degree of $\Gamma$.
This formula is just a guess, it may very well be wrong.

> Question 1: does this algorithm have a name?

> Question 2: by altering the definition of $\overline{f_i}$, can we get more interesting limits of $\overline{f_i}$, for example eigenfunctions of the Laplacian?